# Problems with reading SQL row with java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm working on a java program with an sql database that is a pokemon. I am having problems with putting a row of the database into an array. Here's the part of my code that's causing the problem.

```
String query2 = "SELECT * " + 
                  "FROM Pokedex.typea, Pokedex.Pokemon where Pokemon.ID = " + pk +
                  " AND type1 = type_name";

java.sql.Statement st2 = con.createStatement();   
ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(query2);

int i = 2
    while(rs2.next() && i<19) {
        weaka[i-2] = rs2.getInt(i);
        System.out.println(weaka[i-2]);
        i++;
    }
```

and here is the row that query2 returns(I tested this with mysql workbench):

```
Fire    1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   -1  1   0   0   0   -1  1   -1  4   Charmander  39  52  43  60  50  65  309 Fire    null    Blaze   null    Solar Power NULL
```

I was hoping that this code would put the values from columns 2 through 18 into the array "weaka", but all the code does is continually do

```
weaka[i-2] = rs2.getInt(i);
System.out.println(weaka[i-2]);
```

but it never increments i, never reads the contents of any other column, and never ends. The program just print "1" a couple hundred times and then crashes. Why is the i not iterating?

Can someone help me figure out how to get my code to go down the row and read the contents of column 2 through 18 into the array? Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for both answers. They both worked to get the array reading the row, but the process still goes on longer than it should with both answers. it's like it reads the row multiple times. The code that I gave you was not in a loop, so why is it reading the row multiple times?

also Pokemon.ID is the primary key of my schema, so the query will only return one row.

Comment: Try to use a debugger. `while` loop from the answers could process more then one row only if SQL query returns more then one row from database

Answer (score 0):

The `ResultSet.next()` method attempts to read a *row* from the result set and returns `true` if it manages. What you're doing:

```
while(rs2.next() && i<19) {
    weaka[i-2] = rs2.getInt(i);
    System.out.println(weaka[i-2]);
    i++;
}
```

is reading a row, putting the first value into an array, and read the next row. But there isn't a next row, so the execution stops there and then.

Instead, do this:

```
if (rs2.next()) {
    for (int i=2; i < 19; i++){
        weaka[i-2] = rs2.getInt(i);
        System.out.println(weaka[i-2]);
    }
}
```

If there is more than one row to read, you'll need to handle that, too.

Comment: What happens if ResultSet has multiple rows?

Comment: As I mentioned already, that needs to be handled. But judging by fields names such as `ID`, and variables `pk`, I'm assuming that it's a primary key. My example serves to explain how `ResultSet.next()` ought to be used.